# Need information about JPA based transaction for dynamic SQL table

Tags: sql, hibernate

Firstly, I would like to state our environment details.

We are trying to use EJB-[hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) with [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) Azure to create apps on Azure cloud using Eclipse.

We needed to create and transact on databases dynamically. We are able to create databases dynamically. However, on trying to transact on these we are getting an error:

> "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for connection url"

When we tried statically transacting using [jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa) was not a problem. However, dynamic transactions cannot be done. The entitymanager object is created but not able to connect database.

Could someone help us and explain how we can handle transactions using JPA for dynamically created databases.

Thanks,
Saugata

[edit] We are using the following persistence.xml:

> >org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
>      java:jboss/EDS</jta-data-source> -->
>      net.oauth.database.Co
>      net.oauth.database.Cr
>
> value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory" />
>     value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />

Our code to connect to the db is as follows:
    Map configOverrides = new HashMap();
    configOverrides.put("hibernate.connection.password", "");
    configOverrides.put("hibernate.connection.username", "");
     configOverrides.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    configOverrides.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:sqlsever://;" + "databaseName=;user=;password=");
    EntityManagerFactory factory =        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(ENTERPRISE_UNIT_NAME, configOverrides);

Please note that we are trying to create and connect to db dynamically and hence to do not the db created statically. 
For this we are getting the error:

> "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for connection url"

Answer (score 0):

Create a persistence.xml with a persistence unit and put everything there which is static (eg database dialect, logging parameters, etc.)

Then use the following method to create the entity manager:

```
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties);
```

Supply the variable parameters in the map, like this:

```
properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/test");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", "joe");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", "pass");
```